# Is it possible to create Swift Codable for plain k-v json?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've JSON data like:

```json
{
    "peopleA": "nnll",
    "peopleB": "ihyt",
    "peopleC": "udr",
    "peopleD": "vhgd",
    "peopleE": "llll"
}
```

There're thousands of data like that, basically what I wanna to do is read the JSON file, and fetch the relate info, like: input `peopleC`, return `udr`.

Trying to use some [online solution](https://app.quicktype.io/), I got

```swift
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let peopleA, peopleB, peopleC, peopleD: String
    let peopleE: String
}
```

I know I can refactor the JSON file to:

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "name": "peopleA",
            "info": "nnll"
        },
        {
            "name": "peopleB",
            "info": "ihyt"
        },
        {
            "name": "peopleC",
            "info": "udr"
        }
    ]
}
```

And get the related Swift struct:

```swift
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let candidates: [Candidate]
}

// MARK: - Candidate
struct Candidate: Codable {
    let name, info: String
}
```

I'm just wondering if maybe we could make it work in Swift without postprocessing the json file?

Comment: Maybe override the `init(from decoder: Decoder)` method would help.

Comment: I would simply decode it as a dictionary. That's what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply decode it as a dictionary. Then you can map your dictionary into your array of Candidate structures if you would like to:

---

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let candidates: [Candidate]
}
```

---

```
struct Candidate: Codable {
    let name, info: String
}
```

---

```
let js = """
{
    "peopleA": "nnll",
    "peopleB": "ihyt",
    "peopleC": "udr",
    "peopleD": "vhgd",
    "peopleE": "llll"
}
"""
```

---

```
do {
    let dictionary = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: String].self, from: Data(js.utf8))
    let welcome = Welcome(candidates: dictionary.map(Candidate.init))
    print(welcome)  
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

This will print:

> Welcome(candidates: [Candidate(name: "peopleA", info: "nnll"), Candidate(name: "peopleC", info: "udr"), Candidate(name: "peopleB", info: "ihyt"), Candidate(name: "peopleE", info: "llll"), Candidate(name: "peopleD", info: "vhgd")])